# concurrent server TCP with select in c

Tags: c, select, tcp, server

I have a small problem, in practice I have to let two clients communicate (which perform different functions), with my concurrent server,

I discovered that I can solve this using the select, but if I try to implement it in the code it gives me a segmentation error, could someone help me kindly?

I state that before with a single client was a fable, now unfortunately implementing the select, I spoiled a bit 'all,

I should fix this thing, you can make a concurrent server with select ()?
can you tell me where I'm wrong with this code?

```
int main (int argc , char *argv[])
{
 int list_fd,conn_fd;
 int i,j;
 struct sockaddr_in serv_add,client;
 char buffer [1024];
 socklen_t len;
 time_t timeval;
 char fd_open[FD_SETSIZE];
 pid_t pid;
 int logging = 1;
 char swi;
 fd_set fset;
 int max_fd = 0;
 int waiting = 0;
 int compat = 0;

 sqlite3 *db;
 sqlite3_open("Prova.db", &db);

    start2();
    start3();

    printf("ServerREP Avviato \n");

    if ( ( list_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) ) < 0 ) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (setsockopt(list_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &(int){ 1 }, sizeof(int)) < 0)
        perror("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");

  memset((void *)&serv_add, 0, sizeof(serv_add));   /* clear server address */
  serv_add.sin_family      = AF_INET;
  serv_add.sin_port        = htons(SERVERS_PORT2);
  serv_add.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVERS_IP2);


    if ( bind(list_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_add, sizeof(serv_add)) < 0 ) {
       perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ( listen(list_fd, 1024) < 0 ) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* initialize all needed variables */
    memset(fd_open, 0, FD_SETSIZE);   /* clear array of open files */
    max_fd = list_fd;                 /* maximum now is listening socket */
    fd_open[max_fd] = 1;

    //max_fd = max(conn_fd, sockMED);
        while (1) { 
            FD_ZERO(&fset);
            FD_SET(conn_fd, &fset);
            FD_SET(sockMED, &fset);
            len = sizeof(client);

            if(select(max_fd + 1, &fset, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0){exit(1);}

            if(FD_ISSET(conn_fd, &fset))
            { 
                if ( (conn_fd = accept(list_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &len)) <0 )
                perror("accept error"); 
                exit(-1); 
            } 
         /* fork to handle connection */ 
            if ( (pid = fork()) < 0 ){      
                perror("fork error"); 
                exit(-1); 
            } 
            if (pid == 0) {                 /* child */ 
                close(list_fd);
                close(sockMED); 
                Menu_2(db,conn_fd);
                close(conn_fd); 
                exit(0); 
            } else {                        /* parent */ 
                close(conn_fd); 
        } 
        if(FD_ISSET(sockMED, &fset))
        MenuMED(db,sockMED);
        FD_CLR(conn_fd, &fset);
        FD_CLR(sockMED, &fset);
    } 

    sqlite3_close(db); 
    exit(0); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot understand how you are trying to use `select` here, and why you want to use both `fork` to let a child handle the accepted connection socket, and `select`.

Common designs are:

- multi processing server:

  The parent process setups the listening socket and loops on waiting actual connections with accept. Then it forks a child to process the newly accepted connection and simple waits for next one.
- multi threaded server:

  A variant of previous one. The master thread starts a new thread to process the newly accepted connection instead of forking a new process.
- asynchronous server:

  The server setups a `fd_set` to know which sockets require processing. Initially, only the listening socket is set. Then the main loop is (in pseudo code:

  ```
  loop on select
    if the listening socket is present in read ready sockets, accept the pending connection and add is to the `fd_set`, then return to loop
    if another socket is present in read ready socket
      read from it
      if a zero read (closed by peer), close the socket and remove it from the `fd_set`
      else process the request and return to loop
  ```

  The hard part here is that is processing takes a long time, the whole process is blocked, and it processing involves sending a lot of data, you will have to use `select` for the sending part too...